# Updating Japanese into nfo file turned into garbled character

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

Below is the original nfo file in format that Emby using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<movie>
  <plot />
  <outline />
  <lockdata>false</lockdata>
  <dateadded>2023-02-22 21:52:29</dateadded>
  <title>old title</title>
  <sorttitle>old title</sorttitle>
  <runtime>119</runtime>
  <fileinfo>
    <streamdetails>
      <video>
        <codec>h264</codec>
        <micodec>h264</micodec>
        <bitrate>5744052</bitrate>
        <width>1920</width>
        <height>1080</height>
        <aspect>16:9</aspect>
        <aspectratio>16:9</aspectratio>
        <framerate>29.96973</framerate>
        <language>und</language>
        <scantype>progressive</scantype>
        <default>True</default>
        <forced>False</forced>
        <duration>119</duration>
        <durationinseconds>7168</durationinseconds>
      </video>
      <audio>
        <codec>aac</codec>
        <micodec>aac</micodec>
        <bitrate>256000</bitrate>
        <language>und</language>
        <scantype>progressive</scantype>
        <channels>2</channels>
        <samplingrate>48000</samplingrate>
        <default>True</default>
        <forced>False</forced>
      </audio>
    </streamdetails>
  </fileinfo>
</movie>
```

And I am trying to update the title with below python script

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

title = "千と千尋の神隠し"

# Load the NFO file
filename = "movie.nfo"
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()

# Find the <title> tag and replace its text value with the new title
title_elem = root.find("title")
title_elem.text = title

# Write the updated XML structure to the NFO file
tree.write(filename, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

But after I run the script, the title turned into garbled character

```
<title>σìâπü¿σìâσ░ïπü«τÑ₧ΘÜáπüù</title>
```

I know it is must be an encoding issue, but I do not know how to solve it

The nfo file should be updated to

```
<title>千と千尋の神隠し</title>
```

Comment: How exactly have you tested that result? It turned into garbage *where*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case:

```
print("千と千尋の神隠し".encode('utf-8').decode('cp437'))
```

> ```
> σìâπü¿σìâσ░ïπü«τÑ₧ΘÜáπüù
> ```

The problem is the [`.NFO` file extension](https://www.reviversoft.com/en/file-extensions/nfo):

> The NFO file extension is used for a Warez Information File developed
> by THG. NFO file is basically pirated information pertaining to a
> software or program that is released and distributed by any organized
> group without the knowledge or permission of the creator or owner of
> such programs…

[Wikipedia `.nfo` says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.nfo) - *NFO files often contain elaborate ANSI art* (It is similar to ASCII art, but constructed from a larger set of 256 letters, numbers, and symbols — all codes found in IBM code page `437`, often referred to as extended ASCII).

Oddly enough, `*.nfo` files are always recognized as `OEM-US` encoding **even in Notepad++** (see [this issue at github](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/9153))

Result: your file *is* `UTF8`.

**Proof #1**:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Load the NFO file
filename = "movie.nfo"
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()

# Find the <title> tag
title_elem = root.find("title")
print( title_elem.text)
```

> ```
> 千と千尋の神隠し
> ```

**Proof #2**:

```
filename = "movie.nfo"
with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as fnfo:
    lines = fnfo.readlines()

print([line for line in lines if '<title>' in line])
```

> ```
> ['  <title>千と千尋の神隠し</title>\n']
> ```